# [ndt_matching] gpu version died

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**description**

```
the ndt_matching node with pcl_generic method works fine,
but pcl_anh_gpu method always crashed when started
```

**environment**

```
gpu: nvidia gtx980m
gpu driver version: 410
cuda version: 10.0
cudnn version: 7.6.1.34
ros: melodic
autoware: 1.12.0 and master
```

**steps to reproduce**

```
1. in simulation tab, select bag file (demo data provided by autoware), press start and pause
2. in setup tab, press tf and vehicle model
3. in map tab
    select and press point cloud (demo data provided by autoware)
    select and press vector map (demo data provided by autoware)
    select and press tf (demo data provided by autoware)
4. in simulation tab, press pause again to resume, 
    in rviz, verify that the pcd map and vector map are loaded correctly
5. in sensing tab, click voxel_grid_filter with default parameters
6. in computing tab, click nmea2tfpose with default parameters
    select pcl_anh_gpu method and click ndt_matching
7. in simulation tab, press pause to resume
8. then ndt_matching died with error message as below
```

**error messages**

```
Error: out of memory /home/leon/autoware.ai/src/autoware/core_perception/ndt_gpu/src/VoxelGrid.cu 181 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >' what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument [ndt_matching-1] process has died [pid 8436, exit code -6, cmd /home/leon/autoware.ai/install/lidar_localizer/lib/lidar_localizer/ndt_matching __name:=ndt_matching __log:=/home/leon/.ros/log/a41e9918-b072-11e9-96f6-9cb6d01138d9/ndt_matching-1.log]. log file: /home/leon/.ros/log/a41e9918-b072-11e9-96f6-9cb6d01138d9/ndt_matching-1*.log
```

**contents of ndt_matching-1-stdout.log**

Log file:
method_type: 2
use_gnss: 1
queue_size: 1
offset: linear
get_height: 0
use_local_transform: 0
use_odom: 0
use_imu: 0
imu_upside_down: 0
imu_topic: /imu_raw
localizer: velodyne
(tf_x,tf_y,tf_z,tf_roll,tf_pitch,tf_yaw): (1.2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0)
Update points_map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329433/%5Bndt_matching%5D-gpu-version-died/) by [hit_leon](https://answers.ros.org/users/44332/hit_leon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for reporting the bug.

`pcl_anh_gpu` is an algorithm that consumes a lot of memory.
If the map is large or the resolution of the NDT is small, the memory will be insufficient and the process will die.
A similar bug has been identified for the CPU implementation `pcl_anh`.

Since `pcl_anh_gpu`, `pcl_anh` and `pcl_openmp` have known bugs, I recommend using `pcl_generic`.

If you like, please report the bug to autoware gitlab.
https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/core_perception/issues

---

Originally posted by [Yamato Ando](https://answers.ros.org/users/43573/yamato-ando/) with karma: 231 on 2019-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hit_leon](https://answers.ros.org/users/44332/hit_leon/) on 2019-07-29**:
thanks for your reply, and I have reported this bug to gitlab.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-09-11**:
@yamato-ando Are there Issues on the Autoware.ai Gitlab site for these known bugs? I don't see them anywhere.

**Comment by [Yamato Ando](https://answers.ros.org/users/43573/yamato-ando/) on 2019-09-13**:
@Maximus5684 I'm sorry. Later I will report the bugs I know.